# How to receive html form with hidden input in the server?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I have a page with an html form. A third party application appends a hidden input in the form. How can i read this hidden input in my server side?

Alterantive, cause i dont know exactly the name of the hidden input, I want to be able to read the whole form in the server and then parse it. Is this possible?

I am using JSF and Java managed beans in the server side.

I have seen similar posts but nothing really helped me.
I am really newbie in Javascript , Ajax etc. so please be as much explanatory as possible :)

Thnx

Comment: when the client submits a form, all fields are sent with the request. no matter how these fields were added to the form on the client. So given that you do not know the name of the field you can just exclude those that you know the names of and then figure out the ones that remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I want to be able to read the whole form in the server and then parse it.*

Essentially, your question boils down to *How do I read all request parameters in JSF?*, right?

Well, basically as follows:

```
Map<String, String[]> paramValues = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterValuesMap();

for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : paramValues.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();

    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.printf("Parameter: %s = %s%n", name, value);
    }
}
```